# What happens in a JOIN query when there is a foreign key error?

Tags: sql-server

I've used BULK INSERT without CHECK_CONSTRAINT to populate two related tables.

```
Country
- Id
- Name

Location
- Id
- CountryId
- Name
```

When I query with a JOIN I get no errors and all Locations seem to show a Country:

```
 SELECT l.Id, l.CountryId, c.Name FROM Location l JOIN Country c ON l.CountryId=C.Id;
```

But when I run BULK INSERT with CHECK_CONSTRAINT I get an error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
constraint "FK_Location_CountryId_Country_Id". The conflict occurred in 
database "test", table "dbo.Country", column 'Id'.
```

This doesn't help me identify the row with the error.

What happens in a JOIN query when there is a foreign key error?
And what's the quickest way for me to find the row with the error when performing a BULK INSERT?

Comment: A bad way to figure it out would be to change the bulk insert into a singular insert and use a cursor to iterate over the records. Then when it fails, you can spit out which record is causing the issue.

Comment: You can always insert the data into a table with no queries and do a SELECT of that table where the CountryId is not in your Location table. To do the import you can use something like OPENROWSET or just something like the default import wizard from the ssms.

Comment: @asemprini87 Table with no keys perhaps?

Comment: @ajeh yes, just a plain table with what you are trying to join and Insert.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might have helped:

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE CountryId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Country);
```

But the problem was forgetting to populate the Country table before the Location table.

Answer (score 0):

> When I query with a JOIN I get no errors and all Locations seem to show a Country:

That is because your code is only returning `Locations` that have a `CountryId` that exists in table `Country`.

---

To find the rows in `Location` that do not have a corresponding valid `CountryId` you could use `not exists()` or `not in ()` like so:

```
select *
from Location l 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from Country c 
    where l.CountryId=C.Id
  )
```